# Назначение id в jQuery на лету

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять принцип работы скрипта при изменении id.
Вот есть такой код в html:

```
<button id="hello">
    Вывод сообщения
</button>
<button id="change">
    Изменить вывод
</button>
```

и скрипт:

```
    $('#hello').on ('click', function () {
        alert ('Привет!');
    });
    $('#bye').on ('click', function () {
        alert ('Пока!');
    });
    $('#change').on ('click', function () {
        $('#hello').attr('id','bye');
    });
```

Задумка в том, что при нажатии на кнопку "change" будет меняться id кнопки ("hello" на "bye") и соответственно выводиться другое сообщение. Собственно id меняется, но функция выполняется та, которая назначена для "hello". Почему не подхватывает назначенную для "bye" функцию?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что строчка

```
$('#hello').on ('click', function () { ...
```

находит конкретный элемент по `id` и прикрепляет к нему обработчик события.

А строчка

```
$('#bye').on ('click', function () { ...
```

вообще ничего не находит.

---

```
$(document).on('click', '#hello', function () {
    alert ('Привет!');
});
$(document).on('click', '#bye', function () {
    alert ('Пока!');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!